# How is this Taylor's Theorem?

Tags: calculus, analysis, taylor-expansion

When doing A-levels, we showed that any $n$th degree polynomial function $p(x-a)$ can be expressed in terms of its $n$ derivatives

$$p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{p^{(i)}(a)}{i!}(x-a)^n$$

and this was the Taylor's theorem that we learned. Now at university, in our Analysis II course, we did the following theorem, also dubbed Taylor's theorem:

> If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous function that is differentiable on  $(a,b)$, and $x,x+h\in(a,b)$, then $f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(x+\theta h)h$ for some $\theta\in(0,1)$.

Which we proceeded to prove using the mean value theorem. This seems to me to be quite an unrelated theorem - does it have anything to do with the polynomial expansion in terms of derivatives?

Comment: Search for it on Wikipedia. The theorem is usually stated for any function, not only for polynomials. Of course if don't have a polynomial then you only get an approximation of the true function

Comment: This is *Taylor's theorem* at order $0$. The general Taylor's theorem is the same as for polynomials for functions of class $\mathcal C^n$, except it is an *approximation* formula for the function by it so-called *Taylor's polynomial*. For polynomials, it is an *exact* formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a connection. Let's rewrite your second Taylor's theorem (which is really just a restatement of the Mean Value Theorem) a little. Put $x+h = a$, then

$$ f(x) = f(a) + f^\prime(c)(x - a) $$

where $c = x + \theta h$. This looks remarkably like the linear (first order) Taylor expansion of a function $f(x)$:

$$ f(x) = f(a) + f^\prime(a)(x - a) + R_1(x) $$

where $R_1(x)$ is the remainder of the linear approximation.

So what this tells us is that the exact difference between $f(x)$ and $f(a)$ can be given as something which closely resembles the first-order Taylor expansion. You can repeat this idea up to higher orders, and by the time you generalise it to the $n$th order you'll get back Taylor's Theorem.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up! When I asked my Analysis lecture, he said the process could be repeated recursively to get the full Taylor's Theorem.